# How to avoid CORS error when redirecting from back-end to external provider on localhost

Tags: c#, .net, angular, cors, stripe-payments

So I am implementing `Stripe` into our system. We have an `Angular` application which allows to select a product to purchase. Then it calls our `API`

```
  createPaymentSession(products: Array<number>, subscription: number) {
    return this.http.post<Response<any>>(
      this.baseUrl + 'shopping/payment',
      { products, subscription }
    );
  }
```

forms a checkout and after success, it redirects to generated `Stripe` checkout `URL` like so:

```
        [HttpPost("payment")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePayment(CreateCheckoutRequest request)
        {
            var session = await _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICommerceService>().CreatePaymentSession(request.Products, request.Subscription);
            if (session is not null)
            {
                return Redirect(session.Url);
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

All is working, I just have this problem that it requires `SSL` and I cannot test the flow on `localhost`. I am getting following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_...' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5004/api/shopping/payment') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Is there a way to avoid the error so I can complete the flow on local application?

EDIT:
Stripe's documentation of implementation from [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment):

```
// This example sets up an endpoint using the ASP.NET MVC framework.
// Watch this video to get started: https://youtu.be/2-mMOB8MhmE.

using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Stripe;
using Stripe.Checkout;

namespace server.Controllers
{
  public class PaymentsController : Controller
  {
    public PaymentsController()
    {
      StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_51NAu5ZGVj6xdB6Xmzpl8nniTmtbLiLoGa3IAlTGPu3nsrZ4FsWgL7fnBL3A4CmhMgbQD7cIIuSNR3xkNhesWKMd2003DoZ5MQA";
    }

    [HttpPost("create-checkout-session")]
    public ActionResult CreateCheckoutSession()
    {
      var options = new SessionCreateOptions
      {
        LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
        {
          new SessionLineItemOptions
          {
            PriceData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataOptions
            {
              UnitAmount = 2000,
              Currency = "usd",
              ProductData = new SessionLineItemPriceDataProductDataOptions
              {
                Name = "T-shirt",
              },
            },
            Quantity = 1,
          },
        },
        Mode = "payment",
        SuccessUrl = "http://localhost:4242/success",
        CancelUrl = "http://localhost:4242/cancel",
      };

      var service = new SessionService();
      Session session = service.Create(options);

      Response.Headers.Add("Location", session.Url);
      return new StatusCodeResult(303);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `XMLHttpRequest` usage at client to make a call to create a Checkout Session and redirect to its URL at server, CORS error will be thrown. `XMLHttpRequest` is designed to make a request, get a response back, and then you do something with the response in your code. They are not meant to be used with server-side redirects.

One way to fix this is remove the server-side redirects and return the Checkout Session URL to the client, then perform client-side redirects such as `window.location.href`.

Comment: yeah, but apparently, from Stripe's documentation, they are providing a redirect from the server as an example of how the flow should be implemented. I have attached an example above.

Comment: Stripe uses `<form action="/create-checkout-session" method="POST">` to make a server request to create a checkout session instead of using `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`. You can find it in this step [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#redirect-customers) of the doc.

Comment: To use server-side redirects, you should use <form action> to make a server call.